# How to animate items on ListView/GridView on Windows8

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I have a listview

```
<ListView x:Name="MyList"   ItemsSource="{Binding MyItems}" Width="420" MaxHeight="500"
                 ItemTemplate="{StaticResource MyDataTemplate}"  ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource MyListViewItemStyle}" >
                    <ListView.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <StackPanel >
                                <StackPanel.ChildrenTransitions>
                                <TransitionCollection  >
                                    <EntranceThemeTransition
                                        FromHorizontalOffset="460" />
                                    </TransitionCollection>
                                </StackPanel.ChildrenTransitions>                                
                            </StackPanel>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemsPanel>
                </ListView>
```

I clear `MyItems` from the `ViewModel` and add the new items.

What happens is the animation works for the first time, but when I clear `MyItems` and add new items, nothing happens!

I want to run the animation again when I clear the items and add the new items, can I run it from CodeBehind?

Comment: Try checking out [`ListView.ItemContainerTransitions`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.itemscontrol.itemcontainertransitions.aspx).

Comment: i think first time you initialize your items collection and second time you are clearing it adding news one.if this is the case then reinitialize your collection again.Because it something works one time then it should work second time too.

Answer (score 0):

I've done it in my last project for the listview to have a expandle list. 
My code behind is to remove all the items in the listview.

```
ListView1.Items.Clear();
```

Then i recreate again the items using for each loop.

```
string[] lv = {"item1", "item2", item3"}
foreach (string val in lv)
        {
            var lvi = new ListViewItem { Content = val };
            ListView1.Items.Add(lvi);
        }
```